# toString() giving error when using to pass parameter

Tags: javascript, tostring

toString is giving error `cannot read property 'toString()' of undefined` while using it as

```
document.getElementById('pMonth').addEventListener('click',function(){ calen(this.year.toString()+'-'+(this.currentMonth1-1).toString());},false);
```

but the code is working perfectly while using as

```
var tr=this.year.toString()+'-'+(this.currentMonth1-1).toString();
document.getElementById('pMonth').addEventListener('click',function(){ calen(tr);},false);
```

`this.year` and `this.CurrentMonth1` are numeric value !!
please tell me where i am going wrong !

Comment: try  removing `this.` for variables inside the listener....

Comment: I agree with redflare

Comment: i tried removing 'this' and it's working perfectly , can you explain how it's working without 'this' keyword , as value of 'year' and 'currentMonth1' is not accessible without 'this' in other parts of the code @redflar3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to bind the context to your event handler, since `this` would be referencing to the DOM element returned from `document.getElementById('pMonth')`

So you need:

```
document.getElementById('pMonth').addEventListener(
   'click', 
   function(){
       calen(this.year.toString()+'-'+(this.currentMonth1-1).toString());
   }.bind(this),
   false
);
```

Comment: I don't understand this answer at all. The most likely value for `this` here is going to be `window`

Comment: The object of `this` is based on the context of where the function is being called. In this case, it's called in the click event handler of the element `#pMonth`, so the context would be the element `#pMonth`, you can easily make a test case to try.

Comment: yeah this code is working perfectly , but can you explain what is the value of `this` as in `bind(this)` . and how is the value of two `this` is different in that code !

Comment: `this` keyword is one of the fundamental concept of Javascript, there are many resources from web which probably can explain better than I do, try to read these links:
http://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html, http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascripts-this-with-clarity-and-master-it/